# Trying to get the count for each unique countrycode in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a count of each `continent` from a table named `Country`:

```
SELECT continent, count(*) totalcount from Country
```

It is returning the total amount of records in the table and only one continent is there.

Is something wrong with my syntax? I have found other examples online that look like this, but return all the unique values with a count to accompany them. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please read the help center and atleast format your post properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an aggregation function, all of the other columns selected should be aggregations or mentioned in the group by. MySQL although it has a relaxed approach to this requirement, you should still always try to do it. 
Adding

```
GROUP BY `continent`
```

would work in this case

A list of aggregation functions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

which mentions

> if you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY
>   clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows

some more reading on mysql's implementation of `group by`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by clause:

```
SELECT continent,count(*) totalcount from Country group by continent
```

Comment: Thanks everyone I just saw these answers after finding the information out on my own a little while ago but I appreciate you taking your time to assist

Answer (score 0):

The instruction count(*) is an aggregation instruction and therefore it will return only one line. You should try something like

```
SELECT continent, count(*) totalcount FROM Country GROUP BY continent
```

in order to have the number of countries in each continent...

edit: too late ;)